# CurrentQuestionID not expanding in Exsheets

Tags: exsheets

I would like to be able to call \CurrentQuestionID within a question, specifically in a \IfQuestionPropertyTF statement, but it seems that \CurrentQuestionID is not expanding when called within a command.  See mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\DeclareQuestionProperty{notes}
\DebugExSheets{true}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
 \SetQuestionProperties{notes={blah}}
 \textbackslash\texttt{CurrentQuestionID} is \CurrentQuestionID.
 Calling \textbackslash\texttt{QuestionNumber} with input ``1'' works: 
   Question number is \QuestionNumber{1}
 Calling \textbackslash\texttt{QuestionNumber} with input \textbackslash\texttt{CurrentQuestionID} doesn't work:  
   Question number is \QuestionNumber{\CurrentQuestionID}
 Calling \textbackslash\texttt{IfQuestionPropertyTF} with input ``1'' works: 
   \IfQuestionPropertyTF{notes}{1}{true}{false}
 Calling \textbackslash\texttt{IfQuestionPropertyTF} with input \textbackslash\texttt{CurrentQuestionID} doesn't work:  
   \IfQuestionPropertyTF{notes}{\CurrentQuestionID}{true}{false}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the macros to accept also a control sequence like `\CurrentQuestionID` and expand it before starting their work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareQuestionProperty{notes}
\DebugExSheets{true}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\QuestionNumber}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \exsheets_question_number:o {#2} }
   { \exsheets_question_number:n {#2} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exsheets_question_number:n { o }

\RenewDocumentCommand{\IfQuestionPropertyTF}{smmmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \exsheets_if_question_property:noTF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
   { \exsheets_if_question_property:nnTF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exsheets_if_question_property:nnTF { no }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
 \SetQuestionProperties{notes={blah}}
 \texttt{\string\CurrentQuestionID} is \CurrentQuestionID.

 Calling \texttt{\string\QuestionNumber} with input ``1'' works: 
   Question number is \QuestionNumber{1}

 Calling \texttt{\string\QuestionNumber*} with input \texttt{\string\CurrentQuestionID} works as well:  
   Question number is \QuestionNumber*{\CurrentQuestionID}

 Calling \texttt{\string\IfQuestionPropertyTF} with input ``1'' works: 
   \IfQuestionPropertyTF{notes}{1}{true}{false}

 Calling \texttt{\string\IfQuestionPropertyTF*} with input \texttt{\string\CurrentQuestionID} works as well:  
   \IfQuestionPropertyTF*{notes}{\CurrentQuestionID}{true}{false}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]